# I want to convert a matrix to a list python

Tags: python

Hi there 
I need to convert a matrix to a list as the example below

```
Matrix:
[[  1.   6.  13.  10.   2.]
 [  2.   9.  10.  13.  15.]
 [  3.  15.  13.  14.  16.]
 [  4.   5.  14.  13.   6.]
 [  5.  18.  16.   4.   3.]
 [  6.   7.  12.  18.   3.]
 [  7.   1.   8.  17.  11.]
 [  8.  14.   5.   4.  16.]
 [  9.  16.  18.  17.  15.]
 [ 10.   8.   9.  15.  17.]
 [ 11.  11.  17.  18.  12.]]

List:
[(1, 6, 13, 10, 2),  (2, 9, 10, 13, 15), (3, 15, 13, 14, 16),
 (4, 5, 14, 13, 6),  (5, 18, 16, 4, 3),  (6, 7, 12, 18, 3), 
 (7, 1, 8, 17, 11),  (8, 14, 5, 4, 16),  (9, 16, 18, 17, 15),
 (10, 8, 9, 15, 17), (11, 11, 17, 18, 12)]
```

Thx in adavance

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What is the current saved state of the matrix? Is it in a text file and the text file format is like the first example you gave? Is it stored as a Numpy array or matrix?

Answer (score 13):

Is this a numpy matrix?  If so, just use the `tolist()` method. E.g.:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.matrix([[1,2,3],
               [7,1,3],
               [9,4,3]])
y = x.tolist()
```

This yields:

```
y --> [[1, 2, 3], [7, 1, 3], [9, 4, 3]]
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do it is:

```
result = map(tuple, Matrix)
```

Comment: @gotgenes, correct on both counts. I updated. I generally forget about `chain.from_iterable`. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: I understand downvoting when I misunderstood the question (which didn't happen), but why has the only answer that actually creates a list of tuples been downvoted _after_ I fixed it? Is it because I look like a hippie? If it makes you feel any better (and not that it's any of your damn business) but I've been shaving at least once every two months and am currently wearing a polo. I'm just too much of a lazy hippie to update my picture.

Comment: @aaronsterling Perhaps the down-voter was the lazy one, reading my two comments and without checking the updated code for correctness? I have removed my earlier two comments since this code is correct (making some assumption about the structure of `Matrix`, which is ill-defined by the OP).

Comment: @aaronsterling - Remind me to never post a picture of myself here if looking like a hippie gets you downvoted! :)   At any rate I'm not sure why you got downvoted, either... (+1 from me) Your answer is the only one that actually gives a list of tuples.  I'm leaving mine up just because `ndarray.tolist()` is useful to know about, even it it produces nested lists.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using numpy and you want to just traverse the matrix as a list then you can just

```
from numpy import array
m = [[  1.   6.  13.  10.   2.]
 [  2.   9.  10.  13.  15.]
 [  3.  15.  13.  14.  16.]
 [  4.   5.  14.  13.   6.]
 [  5.  18.  16.   4.   3.]
 [  6.   7.  12.  18.   3.]
 [  7.   1.   8.  17.  11.]
 [  8.  14.   5.   4.  16.]
 [  9.  16.  18.  17.  15.]
 [ 10.   8.   9.  15.  17.]
 [ 11.  11.  17.  18.  12.]]

for x in array(m).flat:
   print x
```

This will not consume extra memory

Comment: It also flattens the array, which isn't want the OP wanted (I think?).  Regardless, you're quite correct in pointing out that there's no need to convert it to a list if you just want to iterate over it.  Simply iterating over the array itself will group the rows, as the OP seems to want.

Answer (score 2):

OR you can use one of those :

```
1- li = list(i for j in yourMatrix for i in j)
2- li = sum(yourMatrix, [])
```