# Trying to converting a matrix 1*3 into a list

Tags: python, numpy

I am currently getting:

```
y=[[ 0.16666667]
[-0.16666667]
[ 0.16666667]]
```

This comes out of a function im using and i need to turn the above into a list in the format below:

```
x= [0.16666667,-0.16666667,0.16666667]
```

I tried list(y) but this does not work, because it returns:

```
[array([ 0.16666667]), array([-0.16666667]), array([ 0.16666667])]
```

How exactly would I do this??

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048792/i-want-to-convert-a-matrix-to-a-list-python/). This may help you.

Comment: It's a common requirement to flatten a nested list, have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python)

Comment: Is y a matrix or an array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
my_list = [col for row in matrix for col in row]
```

Comment: @user1819717 don't forget to accept the answer if it was useful.

Comment: The interpretation of multiple levels of iteration inside a generator expression or list comprehension is something which often confuses people and should thus be used with great care; once you get to the `for` statement, they are handled *left-to-right* rather than the more-obvious-to-me-and-several-other-people-that-I-have-spoken-to-on-the-matter inwards-from-the-right. Although I knew about that, I actually just a few days ago [got caught on it with assignment statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945048)... they work left-to-right too.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the numpy `.tolist()` method:

```
array.tolist()
```

There is also one more advantage to it... It works with `matrix` objects, the list comprehension doesn't. If you want to remove the dimension first you can use numpy methods to do so, such as `array.squeeze()`

Answer (score 1):

Grabs the first element from each sublist, using a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
x = [elt[0] for elt in y]
```